# Check if input is in the database do nothing

Tags: python, html

The problem I want to ask is how can I check if the input is exist in the database so nothing should update. if not commit.
I try to use if, so if input is in the list pass and else add to the database but this is not working by this error"argument of type 'Todo' is not iterable" I think newtodo can not do thing like that so I try to create a new veriable that request.form from the input but still not working

app.py

```
db.create_all()


@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def postmv():
    todos = Todo.query.all()
    num_todos = len(todos)
    if flask.request.method == "POST":
        data = flask.request.form
        new_todo = Todo(
            inputmv=data["inputmv"],
        )
        
        # db.session.add(new_todo)
        # db.session.commit()

        if new_todo in new_todo :
                    pass
        else:
                    db.session.add(new_todo)
                    db.session.commit()
```

html

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="/">
            <input type="text" name="inputmv" required/>
            <input type="submit" value="inputmv!"/>
        </form>
        <form method="POST" action="/delete">
            <input type="text" name="deletemv" required/>
            <input type="submit" value="deletemv!"/>
        </form>
        <ol>
        {% for i in range(num_todos) %}
            <li><b>{{todos[i].inputmv}}</b>;</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ol>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Out of scope for your question, but it's also *very* odd to use a POST request to delete data

Comment: I am new for the html, so what is the normal way to delete data.

Answer (score 0):

just initialize your variables after delete

```
@app.route("/delete", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def deletemv():
    if flask.request.method == "POST":
        
        deletemv = flask.request.form['deletemv']
    
        try:
            for i in range (num_todos):
                if deletemv == todos[i].inputmv:
                    Todo.query.filter_by(id=todos[i].id).delete()
                    db.session.commit()
        except:
            pass

    todos = Todo.query.all()
    num_todos = len(todos)

    return flask.render_template(
        "index.html",
        num_todos=num_todos,
        todos=todos,
    )
```